# WP8.1 Navigation Bar Overlay

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently developing an application in windows phone 8.1 And I am having problems with the soft system navigation bar.

I can hide the bar, but I can't seem to find if it is visible or not.
To hide it, I could use:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
```

The problem is that some phones have it, some don't. I need to find if it is active so that I can bind the height of my VirtualizingStackPanel correctly.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no perfect way to work with the none-hardware nav bar, and i think that your best option here is to subscribe to the [`ApplicationView.VisibleBoundsChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.visibleboundschanged) event,

so basically what you need to do is :

1. set the [`ApplicationViewBoundsMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewboundsmode.aspx) to `UseCoreWindow` so that the content will be laid out in the region occupied by the core phone window :

   ```
   ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
   ```
2. subscribe to the `VisibleBoundsChanged` event and handle you UI changes inside the handler:

   ```
   ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += handler;
   ```

   //...

   ```
   private void handler(ApplicationView sender, object args)
   {
       //handle ui changes
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I reversed engineered the problem. I actually set the bar to false when I first start the app. Then with the event you suggested, If the layout keeps the same visible size, it's because there is no softbar, else, I just re-adjust the layout. Thank you!

Comment: Could there be a more complete example of this posted?  It doesn't seem to work for me.  It seems that the VisibleBoundsChanged event fires every time the app is started regardless of the phone or settings.